# The network connection in my Windows 10 parallels VM isn't working, what is causing this?

Tags: windows-10, mac, virtual-machine, parallels

I installed Parallels VM on my Mac and created a Windows 10 VM. I have a connection problem in the Windows 10 VM but not on my Mac.

I get the following error:

`There is no network adapter on your Mac for the "Parallels Shared #0" virtual network. The network adapter 0 will be disconnected.`

What could cause this?

Comment: This is a poor question. We need more detail :- What adapters are available to the VM, What adapters are configured on the host. What IP addressing scheme for both VM and Host. Also state what trouble shooting you've done, and provide screenshots and error outputs.

Comment: Please Edit your question and add more information

Comment: Have you created any virtual network in your mac.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem after updating parallels. Now I get a popup with the exact same message every time I start a VM an there is no network connection, but it does find the adapter and reports that the cable is unplugged

Comment: If I select bridged instead of shared, it works though

Answer (score 0):

I resolved in this way:

1. Shut down vm;
2. Go to System Preferences > Sharing > Internet and turn on Apple Internet sharing (make sure that the checkbox is checked and blue);
3. Now disable the internet connection checkbox just set up;
4. In vm settings, when you try to choose internet mode, the error message should not appear.

[image]

I don't know why but this may occur due to a driver error. Hope that you can resolve :)

Answer (score -2):

The above could be limited by your IT Security.  You can also go to your the menu of your Parallels.  drop Down Devices/Network/Shared Network (Recommended).  Make sure that is checked off.  you shouldn't need to reboot; it should work automatically.  If it fails, try to reboot your VM.